# Change information (phone number) in header of WordPress site using Veda theme

Tags: themes, database, page-template, headers, contact

The site is located at [www.morrellplumbing.com.au](https://morrellplumbing.com.au/) and the header looks like this:

[image: Header of Site]

I need to change the phone number, but for the life of me, I cannot find where it is stored in the Wordpress dashboard.

Where is this information kept and how do I find and change it?

---

** Edit **

Both the email address and the phone number are clickable, but they don't do anything.

### Header Editor

The theme has a header editor, but it doesn't contain either the phone number or the email address. The Site Identity tab does not include these, nor do any of the others. See attached:

[image]

### Export

A search of the XML file generated by an 'All content' export for the phone number (or parts of it) did not turn it up.

Comment: I don't know the Veda theme or WP Bakery. Do you still have support, can you ask the authors for help? It's a premium theme so we aren't able to just get hold of it to have a look ourselves.

Comment: I'd look through the theme customiser for a header editor if you can find one and see if it's there. Else if you have a database backup that'll be a text file that you can just search for the phone number which should give you an idea if it's stored in the posts table, or wp_options, or wp_usermeta against the first user, or somewhere else.

Comment: @Rup thanks for your comments; see edits.

Comment: WordPress does not have a standard way or storing this sort of thing in classic themes. So the answer will depend entirely on the theme and you’ll need to ask the then author for support.

Comment: @JacobPeattie is it possible it’s hard written in a html file somewhere?

Comment: @DaleM As I said, it depends entirely on the theme. Anything is possible.

Comment: Try searching all of the files in the site for `top-header-contactinfo` which is the CSS class of the box surrounding the phone number.